# How not to call onAppWidgetOptionsChanged on API level<16?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I want to support version 4.0 and up so on the newer versions of Android I want to manually call onAppWidgetOptionsChanged to query approximate size of the widget. I don't want it to crash on version 4.0.

How can I conditionally do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check API version before call onAppWidgetOptionsChanged

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection. To get a list of all public methods of the class:

```
Method[] methods = AppWidgetProvider.class.getMethods();
```

Then loop through these methods. If the desired is present you can invoke it using the `Method` object